# How to display Leaflet Static Labels for objects in a LayerGroup?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to add a static label to a few CircleMarkers I've created.  These markers are added to a LayerGroup and then added to the map.  I've read that I need to call .showLabel() after I've added it to the object to the map.  But since I am building the LayerGroup first, then adding it to the map I'm unsure of how to do this.

I thought about using L.LayerGroup.eachLayer but I'm unsure which object I would actually call the .showLayers() on.  My code is below, any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
  var jsonLayers = new L.LayerGroup();  

  jsonLayers.addLayer(L.geoJson(mapFeature.features[i], {
          style: function (feature) {
                   return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
          },

          onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

          pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    var newCircle = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                          radius: 5,
                          fillColor: fColor,
                          color: "#000",
                          weight: 1,
                          opacity: 1,
                          fillOpacity: 0.8
                  });                                                      

                  newCircle.bindLabel(feature.properties.name, { noHide: true });                                                                                                                
                  return newCircle;
    }
  }));

  map.addLayer(jsonLayers);
```

Comment: When I try: 

        jsonLayers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                layer.showLabel();
        });  

I get an error that showLabel is not a function.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/issues/31 it seems this isn't supported for CircleMarker.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label ?

Comment: @gibbocool Sorry, I should have mentioned that I was already using that plugin.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that static labels are not supported on CircleMarkers.  To solve this, I added code to Leaflet.label to allow this.  I've also issued a [pull request](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/pull/37) in case someone else would like to do the same thing I am doing.